# How to set a timeout for a sql request in camel?

Tags: java, sql, apache-camel

I am using an sql query which takes a while :

```
from(endpoint)
.to("sql:classpath:requests/myRequest.sql?dataSource=MyDataSource&parametersCount=1")
.end()
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to set a timeout for the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to attach `template.queryTimeout=1`

```
from(endpoint)
.to("sql:classpath:requests/myRequest.sql?dataSource=MyDataSource&parametersCount=1&template.queryTimeout=1")
.end()
```

Comment: A follow up question. If the query takes like 30 seconds or so will camel wait for it? Like does camel has some kind of a default timeout or will it simply wait for the results? (I want it to wait for the results without timeout)

Comment: i think there is default timeout of 300 seconds, but this can be easily tested